# Extensions turn off automatically on startup in GNOME 44.1 after upgrading to Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, gnome

I've just upgraded my system to Fedora 38, and it comes with GNOME 44.1 now. However, there are two problems that I've noticed.

When I open the system now, I've got to log in **twice** instead of once; the first time I type in my password, it goes blank for a split second, and reverts back to the login page, and I've got to enter my password once again.

Next, when I'm finally in my Desktop, I see that Extensions are turned off even though I had turned it on in the last session. This happens every time I boot the OS. Here's the list of extensions I've installed:

- Aylur's Widgets
- Dash to Dock
- Dynamic Panel Transparency
- GSConnect
- Useless Gaps
- User themes

I should add that all of them support GNOME 44, but for *Useless Gaps* I had to change its `manifest.json` file to include 44 as the version number.

Is that what's causing the problem?